# Using Variables in <xsl:sort select=""/>

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

Hi am build a generic template to list my content.  But the Content may be sorted on different @'s or node()'s. So want to pass the xPath in.

```
<xsl:variable name="sort" select="@sortBy"/>
<xsl:variable name="order" select="@order"/>

<xsl:for-each select="Content[@type=$contentType]">
  <xsl:sort select="$sort" order="{$order}" data-type="text"/>
  <xsl:sort select="@update" order="{$order}" data-type="text"/>
    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Using a variable to drop in ascending or descending into the `order=""` WORKS.

Why cannot do this on the `select=""` ?

I hoping to make this super dynamic the select variable can be xPtah either @publish or Title/node() or any xPath.

There is no error - It just ignores the sort.

Comment: W3c spec says; 

xsl:sort has a select attribute whose value is an expression.

and expression is delared as;

Expressions occur as the value of certain attributes on XSLT-defined elements and within curly braces

When i add curly brackets I get an XSLT compile error... :{

Comment: Good question (+1). See the answer below :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**This is by design**. The `select` attribute is the only one which doesnt accept AVTs (Attribute - Value Templates).

The usual solution is to define a variable with the name of the child element that should be used as sort key. Below is a small example:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:variable name="vsortKey" select="'b'"/>
 <xsl:variable name="vsortOrder" select="'descending'"/>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
   <xsl:for-each select="*">
    <xsl:sort select="*[name() = $vsortKey]" order="{$vsortOrder}"/>

    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
   </xsl:for-each>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the following XML document**:

```
<t>
  <a>
   <b>2</b>
   <c>4</c>
  </a>
  <a>
   <b>5</b>
   <c>6</c>
  </a>
  <a>
   <b>1</b>
   <c>7</c>
  </a>
</t>
```

**the wanted result is produced**:

```
<a>
   <b>5</b>
   <c>6</c>
  </a>
<a>
   <b>2</b>
   <c>4</c>
  </a>
<a>
   <b>1</b>
   <c>7</c>
</a>
```

Comment: Hmmm, yes see I tried this... except;
<xsl:sort select="*@[name() = $vsortKey]" order="{$vsortOrder}"/>

Things is I need to sort by @attribute or child::*

Answer (score 0):

The `|` (union operator) works... I must have gotten it slightly wrong when tried before. It was @Dimitre Novatchev's  answer lead me down the right path!!

The following works:

```
<xsl:sort select="@*[name()=$sort] | *[name()=$sort]" 
          order="{$order}" data-type="text"/>
```

It allows me to sort on attributes and nodes. Obviously, as long as they don't have the same `name()` but different values.

Comment: @Will: Please do not post to the lower section of the page unless you are posting an actual answer. StackOverflow is not like a classical forum. Thank you. ;)

Comment: Wasn't... was saying this is the anser, sorry bit confused.

Comment: @Will Hancock: Glad this answer was useful. You may even consider accepting it :)