# xslt sorting when applied on number

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I have created the xslt for sorting below xml. The output doesn't seems to be sorted based on AccountNumber. Not sure what was my mistake.

```
<TXLife xmlns="http://ACORD.org/Standards/Life/2">
    <TXLifeRequest>
        <FundCode>LTRT00</FundCode>
        <AccountDescription>CWA – +U</AccountDescription>
        <CurrencyTypeCode>840</CurrencyTypeCode>
        <TransExeDate>2013-04-20</TransExeDate>
        <AccountNumber>34142</AccountNumber>
        <PaymentAmt>300.000000000</PaymentAmt>
        <ReversalInd>0</ReversalInd>
    </TXLifeRequest>
    <TXLifeRequest>
        <FundCode>LTRW00</FundCode>
        <AccountDescription>CWA – +U</AccountDescription>
        <CurrencyTypeCode>124</CurrencyTypeCode>
        <TransExeDate>2013-04-20</TransExeDate>
        <AccountNumber>14142</AccountNumber>
        <PaymentAmt>250.000000000</PaymentAmt>
        <ReversalInd>0</ReversalInd>
    </TXLifeRequest>   
</TXLife>
```

XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:ns="http://ACORD.org/Standards/Life/2">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
     <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>


    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>


    <xsl:template match="@ns:*">
        <xsl:attribute name="{local-name()}">
            <xsl:value-of select="." />
        </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:template>


    <xsl:template match="/">

           <xsl:for-each select="/ns:TXLife/ns:TXLifeRequest">

               <xsl:sort select="ns:AccountNumber" order="ascending" data-type="number"/>

           </xsl:for-each>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="*"></xsl:apply-templates> 

    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The output :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TXLife xmlns="http://ACORD.org/Standards/Life/2">
   <TXLifeRequest>
      <FundCode>LTRT00</FundCode>
      <AccountDescription>CWA – +U</AccountDescription>
      <CurrencyTypeCode>840</CurrencyTypeCode>
      <TransExeDate>2013-04-20</TransExeDate>
      <AccountNumber>34142</AccountNumber>
      <PaymentAmt>300.000000000</PaymentAmt>
      <ReversalInd>0</ReversalInd>
   </TXLifeRequest>
   <TXLifeRequest>
      <FundCode>LTRW00</FundCode>
      <AccountDescription>CWA – +U</AccountDescription>
      <CurrencyTypeCode>124</CurrencyTypeCode>
      <TransExeDate>2013-04-20</TransExeDate>
      <AccountNumber>14142</AccountNumber>
      <PaymentAmt>250.000000000</PaymentAmt>
      <ReversalInd>0</ReversalInd>
   </TXLifeRequest>
</TXLife>
```

Not sure what i am missing in xslt. I tried with data-type="text" but output is unsorted still.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not outputting any thing in your `for-each` loop.
Move the `apply-templates` into the `for-each`. Something like following should do:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="/ns:TXLife/ns:TXLifeRequest">
        <xsl:sort select="ns:AccountNumber" order="ascending" data-type="number"/>
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="*"></xsl:apply-templates>      
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: what if i add  <xsl:sort select="ns:ReversalInd" order="ascending"/> so that the sorting is done on multiple elements that is AccountNumber and ReversalInd. When i add this statement the output still not sorted... should i use some other mechanism for sorting multiple elements ? please advise.

Comment: Have a look to e.g: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3590194/xslsort-an-xml-file-using-multiple-elements.

Comment: Thank you. But i tried adding <xsl:for-each select="ns:TXLifeRequest">
            <xsl:sort select="normalize-space(concat(ns:AccountNumber, ' ', ns:ReversalInd))"/>
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:apply-templates></xsl:apply-templates>
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:for-each>.    And the output is still in unsorted order.

Comment: you have to change the  data-type. But this will only work if your AccountNumber is sortable as string.