# Pass parameter from jsp into xsl

Tags: xml, jsp, xslt

My code below seems logical however i don't know why the sorting doesn't work with the error "**Variable or parameter 'sort' is undefined.'**"? Im suspecting there are something wrong with declaring param in xsl. Could anyone point my mistake? thanks

java code to pass parameter

```
String sort = "rating";
transformer.setParameter("sort", sort); /It will control the sort in xsl
```

xml file

```
    <?xml version="1.0" ?>

<cd>
  <title>A Funk Odyssey</title>
  <artist>Jamiroquai</artist>

  <tracklist>
    <track id="1">
      <title>Feels So Good</title>
      <time>4:38</time>
      <rating>2</rating>
    </track>

    <track id="2">
      <title>Little L</title>
      <time>4:10</time>
      <rating>5</rating>
    </track>

    <track id="3">
      <title>You Give Me Something</title>
      <time>5:02</time>
      <rating>3</rating>
    </track>

    <track id="4">
      <title>Corner of the Earth</title>
      <time>3:57</time>
      <rating>1</rating>
    </track>
  </tracklist>


</cd>
```

This is my xsl

```
            <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
    <xsl:param name="sort" select="title"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <table border="1">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th><a href="#">Title</a></th>
                    <th><a href="#">Time</a></th>
                    <th><a href="#">Rating</a></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <xsl:for-each select="cd/tracklist/track">
                    <xsl:sort select="$sort"/>
                    <tr>
                        <td><xsl:value-of select="title" /></td>
                        <td><xsl:value-of select="time" /></td>
                        <td><xsl:value-of select="rating" /></td>
                    </tr>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your `xsl:param` declaration you are trying to default to `$sort` which is not defined at the time `xsl:param` is evaluated. It does look like a reference to itself.

If you don't need a default then just change your parameter declaration to:

```
<xsl:param name="sort"/>
```

or default to a string value:

```
<xsl:param name="sort" select="'title'"/>
```

or

```
<xsl:param name="sort">title</xsl:param>
```

That said, we have only addressed the parameter declaration issue. Now on to sorting. The `xsl:sort` needs an [expression](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#dt-expression), it won't convert a string value into XPath like you expect it to.

Here's **a solution**: [Using Variables in `<xsl:sort select=""/>`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2328896/using-variables-in-xslsort-select).

You would basically do something like:

```
<xsl:sort select="*[name() = $sort]"/>
```

Comment: @anonymous, I explained how you should use an XPath expression `*[name() = $sort]` to sort "dynamically"